# Change iPhone earbud button behavior

Tags: iphone, ipod, settings

I recently bought an iPhone 3gs. It comes with a pair of apple earbuds that have a remote and a microphone.

I used to have an iPod, that has a set of earbuds that have a remote but not a microphone. When I long pressed the center button of the remote on the earbuds, the iPod said the title and artist of the current playing song.

On the iPhone though, when I long-press the center button (of the remote with microphone), it starts voice control.

Is there a way to change the iPhone settings to resemble the iPod settings? I don't ever use voice control, yet I do use the microphone for calling people while on my bike.

Comment: It is possible to turn off Voice Control, but I have never done so, so I would have no idea what happens with a long button press after you do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the beep sounds you can ask:

"What song is this?"

It will speak the title, and artist. There isn't a way to turn this off sadly.

Comment: what no way? What should I ask exactly?

Comment: What song is this

Comment: I always used to use 'Who sings this?'. There are a handful of aliases all revolving around a few keywords I'm sure.